# IF function calculates result correctly, then evaluates to #N/A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following function:
`=IF($C3="I_sc",CORREL(INDIRECT(J2&ROW($C4)&":"&J2&ROW()+MATCH("I_sc",INDIRECT("c"&ROW($C4)&":c2300"),0)),INDIRECT(J1&ROW($C4)&":"&J1&ROW()+MATCH("I_sc",INDIRECT("c"&ROW($C4)&":c"&"2300"),0))),"")`

It gives `#N/A` as a result. However, when I go through it step-by-step with the 'Evaluate formula', at the last step it gives:
[image]

Then:
[image]

What could go wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: The #N/A error generally indicates that a formula can’t find what it’s been asked to look for. Check the logical_test in IF formula.

Comment: Actually, I just evaluated the formulas that generates the address in new cells (result is e.g C4:C44), then referenced this cell in indirect. I did not change anything else, just moved part of the formula to a new cell. Now it works...

Comment: Most common cause of the #N/A error is with is,, if a formula can't find a referenced value. So  please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us you are using so far and let us test the formula !